# Laravel s3 image upload not working but retriving does

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload image to s3 bucket using Laravel.

Retriving image is working fine:

```
$path = Storage::disk('s3')->url('some-image-name.jpg');
Log::info($path);
// local.INFO: "https:\/\/bucket-name.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com\/some-image-name.jpg"
```

But when I try to upload image I always get false boolean:

```
if ($image = $request->file('featured_image')) {
     $path = Storage::disk('s3')->put($image->getClientOriginalName(), file_get_contents($image));
     Log::info($path);
}

// local.INFO: false
```

Does anyone have idea what am I doing wrong?
Since retriving image is working fine aws credentials in env file I guess are correct.

Answer (score 0):

that way of uploading a file return a boolean, true means successful uploading.
I use these methods to retrieve the url:

```
     `$path = $request->file('your file name')->store('image','s3');
      $path = Storage::disk('s3')->url($path);
      error_log($path);//this is a S3 url`
```